# How to increment the animation time in CSS3

Tags: css

I have a div with the css:

```
#six {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
-webkit-animation: myfirst 5s infinite;
-webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
animation: myfirst 5s infinite;
animation-delay: 2s;
position: absolute;
left: 100px;
top: 210px;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
    0%   {background: red;}
    25%  {background: yellow;}
    30%  {background: red;}
}


/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes myfirst {
    0%   {background: red;}
    25%  {background: yellow;}
    30%  {background: red;}
}
```

As you can see it simply makes the background flash yellow every five seconds. How can I have that five seconds change every loop? For example the first pass takes 5 seconds, then the next takes 4, and then 3, 2, 1 and so forth?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you would have to use javascript/jquery for this.

Comment: you could extend your animation to support it, so your total animation will be 15 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You could extend your animation to do it for you:

```
@keyframes myfirst {
    0% {background: red;}
    16.6666% {background: yellow;}
    33.3333% {background: red;}
    46.6666% {background: yellow;}
    60% {background: yellow;}
    70% {background: red;}
    80% {background: yellow;}
    86.6666% {background:red;}
    93.3333% {background:yellow;}
    96.6666% {background:red;}
    100% {backgrond:yellow};
}
```

here is a [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxbMBv)